# QMainWindow crashes when using QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt4, qcombobox, qmainwindow

I have a problem with my application in Qt, I use a QMainWindow and try to set up 2 QComboBox like I did for other widgets but the application crashes at the setupUi :

Voilà ma classe MainWindow, elle fonctionnait parfaitement et s'affichait jusqu'à ce que j'ajoute les 2 Combobox.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        MainWindow(Map *inMap, int dim1, int dim2);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:
        void boutonClicked();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *_ui;
        QPushButton *_bouton;
        Canvas *_canvas;
        QComboBox *_boxDim1;
        QComboBox *_boxDim2;
};
```

Une fois les ComboBox ajoutées, le programme crashe à l'exécution du constructeur :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(Map *inMap, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    _ui->setupUi(this);
    _boxDim1 = new QComboBox();
    _boxDim2 = new QComboBox();
    _canvas = new Canvas(inMap, dim1, dim2);
    _bouton = new QPushButton("Test !");
    _bouton->setToolTip("Bouton a push");
    _bouton->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    connect(_bouton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(boutonClicked()));
    QWidget *q = new QWidget();
    setCentralWidget(q);
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout();
    mainLayout->addWidget(_canvas, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(_bouton, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    q->setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

Après débuggage dans ddd, le point exact du segfault correspond à :

```
_ui->setupUi(this);
```

Et à l'intérieur de cette fonction :

```
void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
    if (MainWindow->objetName().isEmpty())
        MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
    MainWindow->resize(800, 600);
    centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow)  /// Segfault ici.
```

Je dois avouer que je ne saisis pas d'où vient le problème puisque l'ajout et la création du QPushButton et du Canvas ont quant à eux parfaitement fonctionné.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_ui` variable is not initialized, that's why it crashes. You need something like: `_ui = new Ui::MainWindow();` ... also, it's good habit to have `MainWindow` take a `QObject` parameter as the parent in the second constructor. Or just use the first one and add the extra parameters you need.

Comment: It was indeed the _ui not initialized.
What surprises me is that it worked until there without this initialization, most likely because project was not cleaned.